# javascript create predefined private variable inside a function dynamically

Tags: javascript, closures

I am trying to create a predefined private variable inside a function dynamically.
The concept I am using, is function return from within a closure block
Like this:-

```
var bar = (function (){
  var foo = "Hello World";
    return function () {
    console.log(foo);
  } 
}());

bar();
```

This is the code that i am using to create an equivalent dynamic expression of the above execution

```
var createClosure = function(fn) {
  var __fn = function () {
    var foo = "Hello World";
    return fn;
  }
  return __fn();
}

var bar = createClosure(function () {
  console.log(foo);
});

bar();
```

but running the above code gives me `ReferenceError: foo is not defined`
What should be the equivalent representation of a function return from a closure block?

Comment: Foo is defined in a function that's defined in yet another function-the var keyword inside a function scopes that variable to that function only. It's not clear what you're trying to do-you say you want a private variable and appear surprised when you have one.

Comment: you cant access variable foo from the anonymous function`s scope because it was defined in another scope..., but you can pass it as a variable to that function

Comment: I don't appear surprised when i have one, i juat want to re-create the 1st code in a dynamic pattern. That's what i think i have asked

Comment: why not implement using classes?

Comment: @WalksAway: Because classes have nothing to do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as close as you can get:

```
function createClosure(fn) {
  const baz = {};
  baz.foo = "Hello World";
  return () => fn(baz);
}
const bar = createClosure(baz => console.log(baz.foo));

bar();
```

Or just pass in `foo` as an argument directly. But you can not just make `foo` exist in another scope. So you could obviously make it global but that wouldn't be a good idea either.

Comment: can you pleas explain this line return () => fn(baz);

Comment: @SouparnoMajumder it's the same as `function() { return fn(baz); }` but in modern JavaScript aka ECMAScript 6.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an way out that I have found, let me know, if this is the correct approach.

```js
var createClosure = function(fn) {
  var __fn = function () {
    var foo = "Hello World";
    var entire = fn.toString();
    var body = entire.substring(entire.indexOf("{") + 1, entire.lastIndexOf("}"));
    return function () {
      eval(body);
    }
  }
  return __fn();
}

var bar = createClosure(function () {
  console.log(foo);
});

bar();
```

Comment: No, that's a terrible approach. You just try to change scope using evil `eval` which works but should not be done and I bet it has much worse performance than any other approach.